# Multi language font

Tags: fonts

Is there any way or any font family that supports both English and Persian language like tahoma?

I am a web developer and new in Ubuntu, I want to write my code in English and Persian language and it is important to me my code looks good.

Comment: Welcome to AU! I think this question doesn't pertain to Ubuntu in particular. You may have more luck asking it on [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, as a web developer, you should use standard and universal fonts, like arial, times new roman,... these fonts are available in all platforms. (now we have web fonts which has changed this rule little bit)

But remember that your visitors should have your font. you cannot use a font which is only available in Ubuntu. So only use universal fonts or web fonts.

If you want to use tahoma, you should install it in Ubuntu